# OpenGL ES Learning - some question about rotating

Tags: opengl-es

Hy there! I am very new to OpenGL ES, i saw many examples in the net, but i have some question about the rotations.

How i can do double rotating at one time? So I need to rotate an object on its center, and at the same time, I need to rotate this object on a circle, that has a center point, in the space.

The second thing:

I create this code:

```
glLoadIdentity...
glTranslateF 0,0,0..
glRotateF...

drawSomeObject...

glLoadIdentity...
glTranslateF 0,3,0..
glRotateF...

drawSomeObject...
```

It is very good, with this code I can rotate my drawing objects on it's own center. But how I can rotate or translate all my objects as a group?

so something this:

```
//translate, and rotate all in the group1
glTranslateF 0,0,0..
glRotateF...

GROUP1

glLoadIdentity...
glTranslateF 0,0,0..
glRotateF...

drawSomeObject...

glLoadIdentity...
glTranslateF 0,3,0..
glRotateF...

drawSomeObject...

END GROUP1


//translate, and rotate all in the group1
glTranslateF 2,0,0..
glRotateF...

GROUP2

glLoadIdentity...
glTranslateF 0,0,0..
glRotateF...

drawSomeObject...

glLoadIdentity...
glTranslateF 0,3,0..
glRotateF...

drawSomeObject...

END GROUP2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the following scheme (pseudocode):

```
LoadIdentity
Translate (Group Translation) 
Rotate(Group Rotation) 
PushMatrix 

Translate Object1
Rotate Object1
DrawObject1

PopMatrix

PushMatrix

Translate Object2
Rotate Object2
DrawObject2

PopMatrix

...
```

So do not return to Identity for each object, but rather return to the group state, which can easily be preserved using PushMatrix and PopMatrix on the modelview matrix. Those commands store the current state on an internal OpenGL stack (PushMatrix) and retrieve the matrix from the stack at a later point (PopMatrix).

Here is a link to a related tutorial: 
http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/pop_and_push_matrices.html